# Count the number of similar values with same indices in two arrays MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to count the number of similar elements in two arrays, which can be done by the intersect function but I need to get only the values which are similar and have the same index. Any ideas?

Comment: is it gonna work on arrays?

Comment: and tol should be zero if am looking for exact values nnz(abs(A-B)=0) ?

Comment: @SMH - Yes David's method should work, but if your values are floating point, I would not set this to 0 due to floating-point precision error... set it to something small... like `1e-10`.  Only set to 0 if your values are integer... and if that's the case, you might as well do `nnz(A == B)`.

Comment: And you can leave off the `nnz` if you want the indices at which the similar values occur

Comment: @beaker - I'd wrap this in a `find` call if you want the indices too: `find(A == B)`.

Comment: @David thanks a lot, please post it as an answer as it works.

Comment: @rayryeng true, if you're looking for the indices themselves... not necessary if you're using it for logical indexing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for how many entries in the two matrices are "nearly" the same, then set some tolerance `tol`, and then you want to find how many corresponding entries in your matrices (call them `A` and `B`) differ by less than `tol`.

```
abs(A-B)<tol
```

is a matrix the same size as `A` and `B` which has a 1 where the elements are close together, and a 0 where they're not. You can use

```
[i,j]=find(abs(A-B)<tol)
```

to get the positions of the nearly-mathcing elements, or

```
nnz(abs(A-B)<tol)
```

to just count how many values nearly-match.